# How does Backbone initial route get called after document ready?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Level 7 of [codeschool.com](http://www.codeschool.com) Backbone course had the following code below and stated that the entire thing could be kicked off with the following jquery

```
$(function(){ TodoApp.start() })
```

which will call `Backbone.history.start`. But how does the call to `Backbone.history.start` eventually lead to `index` being called so that `fetch` is called to populate the model collection `todoList`.

```
var TodoApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "": "index", "todos/:id": "show" },
  initialize: function() {
    this.todoList = new TodoList();
    this.todosView = new TodoListView({collection: this.todoList});
    $('#app').append(this.todosView.el);
  },
  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  },
  index: function(){
    this.todoList.fetch();
  },
  show: function(id){
    this.todoList.focusOnTodoItem(id);
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js), you can see what is happening.

At the end of `History.start`, you can see that it calls `loadUrl`, which looks like this:

```
// Attempt to load the current URL fragment. If a route succeeds with a
// match, returns `true`. If no defined routes matches the fragment,
// returns `false`.
loadUrl: function(fragmentOverride) {
  var fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragmentOverride);
  var matched = _.any(this.handlers, function(handler) {
    if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
      handler.callback(fragment);
      return true;
    }
  });
  return matched;
},
```

When you add routes, they are added to `this.handlers`.  Since there is a handler that matches 'index' that callback is called.